# Curvature condition in inexact line search

Tags: optimization, soft-question, terminology, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the Wolfe inexact line search, why do we call the following condition as ``curvature condition"
$$d_k^T \nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k d_k) \ge c_2  d_k^T \nabla f(x_k)?$$

I was trying to get an explanation through Hessian but failed. Do you have any answer why we refer the above condition as ``curvature condition"?

Comment: [Armijo rule and curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions#Armijo_rule_and_curvature)

Comment: Why "curvature" is not given in your link. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The link clearly states that this condition "ensures that the slope has been reduced sufficiently". Curvature is the gradient is some direction, meaning $d_k^T\nabla f(x_k)$ is a curvature. The reason this result is desirable is that as an unconstrained function approaches a local optimum, the slope decreases (until reaching zero).

Comment: I am not able to get "Curvature is the gradient is some direction, meaning dTk∇f(xk) is a curvature". dTk∇f(xk) is directional derivative. How can it be "curvature"? Do you have any reference or mathematical reason?